# Regex for filtering out unicode \\u style characters

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I have a bunch of strings that look like

```
"The\\u00a0discrepancies\\u00a0experienced"
```

and I want to filter out the `\\u00a0` and replace them with `' '`

Naively I tried something like

```
const unicodeRegexp = new RegExp('\\u00a0', 'g')
const filterKey = string => string.replace(unicodeRegexp, ' ')
```

but a quick test of `filterKey("The\\u00a0discrepancies\\u00a0experienced")` returns the string unfiltered.

What's going on here?

Comment: Do the strings contain two literal backslashes before the `u`, or one?

Comment: The \ needs to be escaped.

Comment: Don't ever use `new RegExp` unless you need to dynamically create a pattern from a variable - use regex literals instead, to avoid the need for double-escaping

Comment: so in summary my filter is fine, it's the input strings that are wrong.  I should be filtering `"The\u00a0discrepancies\u00a0experienced"` instead. I got my input string by copying some output from the console.  Therein lay my error.

Comment: @DaveSag For a string containing double backslashes, you will need to escape each of the backslashes in the regex. The most straightforward way then, is to write `string.replace(/\\\\u00a0/g, ' ');` But if you want to use a string literal as an input to a regExp object, then you will need to escape each of those backslashes _again_, resulting in `const unicodeRegexp = new RegExp('\\\\\\\\u00a0', 'g');` That is why a RegExp object is not recommended in this case.